# Convert integer to class Date

Tags: r, date, r-faq

I have an integer which I want to convert to class `Date`. I assume I first need to convert it to a string, but how?

My attempt:

```
v <- 20081101
date <- as.Date(v, format("%Y%m%d"))
```

> Error in charToDate(x) :    character string is not in a standard
> unambiguous format

Using `paste()` works, but is that really the correct way to do the conversion?

```
date <- as.Date(paste(v), format("%Y%m%d"))
date
[1] "2008-11-01"

class(date)
# [1] "Date"
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`as.character()` would be the general way rather than use `paste()` for its side effect

```
> v <- 20081101
> date <- as.Date(as.character(v), format = "%Y%m%d")
> date
[1] "2008-11-01"
```

(I presume this is a simple example and something like this:

`v <- "20081101"`

isn't possible?)

Comment: @DavidArenburg I think I have a typo as I've never, not once, used `as.Date` the way I show above.

Answer (score 19):

Another way to get the same result:

```
date <- strptime(v,format="%Y%m%d")
```

Comment: interesting. I didn't realize that `strptime` would automatically coerce/handle numeric values ...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ymd` from `lubridate`

```
lubridate::ymd(v)
#[1] "2008-11-01"
```

Or `anytime::anydate`

```
anytime::anydate(v)
#[1] "2008-11-01"
```